# Java8 Function apply method with a implementation

Tags: java, function, lambda, apply

My codes are here. My puzzle is in the main method of `Test.java`, the first case prints the result **using its implementation**, while another as a normal lambda expression prints what it actually is. Also I wanna know if they have the same method signature causing the problem.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Function<ApplyService, Class<? extends ApplyService>> f1 = ApplyService::run;

        System.out.println(f1.apply(new ApplyService1())); 
        // class Function.ApplyService1 -  It's strange, got a result with 'ApplyService1.run'

        //        
        Function<ApplyService, Class<? extends ApplyService>> f2 = Abc::run2;

        System.out.println(f2.apply(new ApplyService1())); // null as wish
    }
}

interface Abc {
    static Class<? extends ApplyService> run2(ApplyService app) {
        return null;
    }
}

interface ApplyService {
    default Class<? extends ApplyService> run() {
        return null;
    }
}

class ApplyService1 implements ApplyService{
    public Class< ? extends ApplyService> run(){
        return this.getClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first function `Function<ApplyService, Class<? extends ApplyService>> f1 = ApplyService::run;` is equivalent to :

```java
Function<ApplyService, Class<? extends ApplyService>> f1 = apService -> apService.run();
```

So, while passing an object of type `ApplyService1` the implemented method in `ApplyService1` is invoked.

But the second function `Function<ApplyService, Class<? extends ApplyService>> f2 = Abc::run2;` is equivalent to :

```java
Function<ApplyService, Class<? extends ApplyService>> f2 = apService -> Abc.run2(apService);
```

Since `Abc::run2` is static method reference, the input `ApplyService` object is passed to the `run2` method.

Answer (score 1):

`ApplyService::run` is a "Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type" as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). Notice how `run` is an instance method, so you would need an instance to call it. You didn't specify any instance of `ApplyService` in the method reference (you just said `ApplyService::run`), so instead, when you invoke the method reference, the first argument you pass to `apply` is used as the instance on which to call the instance method.

In this case, `new ApplyService1()` is the instance on which you call `run`, so when you do:

```
f1.apply(new ApplyService1())
```

you are actually calling:

```
new ApplyService1().run()
```

Notice how the *argument* becomes the instance on which you call the method.

In the case of `Abc::run2`, it is a "Reference to a static method", so none of that "parameter becoming the instance on which you call the method" shenanigan happens, and it works as you expect.